# Unable to load index.php at localhost

Tags: php, apache

Attempting to access localhost results in a blank screen. However, syntax checks all pass. These lines are shown in the apache2 error.log:

```
[Wed May 23 15:42:40.239069 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 13581] [client 127.0.0.1:55796] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed May 23 15:42:40.239099 2018] [php7:error] [pid 13581] [client 127.0.0.1:55796] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

The files in question are a backup from another server, where they work fine. I had them copied to my downloads directory, then moved with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mv * /var/www
```

Not quite sure what permission is required from that first line. The permissions should have been preserved as -rw-rw---- when I took them from the remote server. What else am I missing?

In case it matters, Ubuntu 18.04, and PHP 7.2.

Comment: what is the full path of index.php on your localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run `ls -la` you'll see your permissions are incorrect. Run this for correct site permissions:

```
$ sudo find /path/to/site -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
$ sudo find /path/to/site -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

the first applies `644` to files and the next does `755` to directories.